# converting a No. literal from 64 to 32 bit compiler in ubuntu

Tags: c, compiler-construction, bit-manipulation, bit, bit-shift

As far as I know in 64 bit compiler, (it depends on the compiler) the max size for unsigned long long could be like for instance **18446744073709551615ull** , So I tried to search and replace the literal to **-1ul** when I wanted my .c program being compiled by a 32bit compiler and it did work since it was equal to 2^64 and all 64 bit were 1, so the representation in 32 bit was -1ul(I think based on two's complement)

But I was wondering for the No.  **9223372036854775808ull** since it is 2^(64-1) , what will be the 32bit literal? -2ul or 1ul????

Can anyone explain this conversion process to me? got confused somehow...

Amir

Comment: `9223372036854775808ull ` is `2^63`, not `2^64 - 1`.

Comment: 2^31 = 2,147,483,647 ...

Comment: @Mysticial : Yeah, I meant 2^(64-1) , that was a typo ;p , My question is still unanswered...

Comment: no, 2^31 = 2147483648

Answer (score 1):

`9223372036854775808ull` is `0x8000000000000000` in hex, and becomes `0x00000000` (last eight hex-digits) when you put it into variable of `int32` type.

It seems you need to learn basics about storing data in binary format. Just read related [wiki pages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) and some [articles](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~tomf/notes/cps104/twoscomp.html) and practice in converting numbers between different representations manually (on a paper).

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but I know how to convert them. based on your explanation, 2^64 which is 0x10000000000000000,  gonna be 0x00000000 as well, but it is -1 (after 2's complement)

Comment: @Amir No, 2^64 is 0, `-1` `is 2^64 - 1` (which usually is `ULLONG_MAX`).

Comment: @DanielFischer : so what is 9223372036854775808ull=2^63 ?

Comment: @Amir `0x8000000000000000`. If `unsigned long long` is exactly 64 bits, also `-9223372036854775808ull` produces the same value. I'm afraid I don't understand your confusion. In C, unsigned arithmetic is arithmetic modulo 2^WIDTH, the maximal representable number is `(2^WIDTH) - 1`, every result that would mathematically be larger than that or smaller than 0 is reduced modulo 2^WIDTH.

Comment: @Amir you can't replace `9223372036854775808ull` with another initializer. It's positive value in `signed long long`, so the trick with negative number won't work here.

Comment: @DanielFischer tnx both for the comments, my confusion was based on a "compilation error : value too large to represent" , since I was compiling an optimized code of a 64bit compiler on a 32bit one. that was why i wanted to make any necessary changes in order to convert the literal to 32bit segments. so you suggest me to  do : "sed -i 's/9223372036854775808/0x8000000000000000/g'" and that will fix this error ?

Comment: @Amir this depends on what this value should represent. You probably need to use one of constants defined in `limits.h` header file. Maybe `INT_MAX + 1`.

Comment: @Amir That has nothing to do with whether the code is compiled for 32-bit or 64-bit platforms. If the compiler supports `unsigned long long` (with at least 64 bits, as required by the standard), using `9223372036854775808ull` _must_ work. A compilation error on that indicates that the compiler doesn't support `unsigned long long` (a C89 compiler?), and then no alternative representation will work either. If you omitted the type suffix `ull`, then the problem is that a decimal constant without suffix has signed type, and 2^63 doesn't fit in a `long long` (it's one more than `LLONG_MAX`).

Comment: @DanielFischer , uhum, i got it. yes, it doesn't support ull (its c89), but the thing i did for the 18446744073709551615ull was changing it to "-1ul", and it did work. that was why i was wondering if we can do the same for a 2^63ul. In general, what are we suppose to do in these cases?